# Adding data to two Class objects that share a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm still new to working with entity Framework, I have two Class objects, Loans and BalanceAndInterest. One-to-many relation respectively.

I'm able to setup the object to store to the Loans object, but I'm sure how I'm supposed to add the data to BalanceAndInterest and maintain its relationship.

I've only ever had to work with single class objects before and I really to know who to make this work.

Class objects:

```
public class Loan
{
    public Loan() {

        BalanceAndInterest = new List<BalanceAndInterest>();
    }

    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public string LoanName { get; set; }

    public DateTime LoanDueDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BalanceAndInterest> BalanceAndInterest { get; set; }
}


public class BalanceAndInterest
{
    public BalanceAndInterest() { }

    public int BalanceAndInterestId { get; set; }

    public int CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public int InterestRate { get; set; }

    public virtual Loan Loan { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying load date here :

```
loan = new Loan
                {
                    //LoanID
                    LoanName = tbxName.Text,
                    LoanDueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerFirstDueDate.Text),
                    BalanceAndInterest/// here were I'm getting lost


                };
```

Comment: What are you loading data from?  I'm assuming when you say "load data" that what you actually mean is that you are trying to create a new object to propagate to the database?

Comment: Correct. I'm loading data form a form Fields that corresponded to that classes

Comment: What does the `BalanceAndInterest` data look like on the form?  You essentially have a one to many relationship, meaning that `BalanceAndInterest` would need to be a collection containing zero or more records associated with the loan.

Comment: hmmm Example of data would be : 
Loan one )  name , interestRate, PrincipleBalance, paymentDate 
OR
Loan two ) name , interestRate1, PrincipleBalance1, interestRate2, PrincipleBalance2,  paymentDate (etc.)

Comment: I've ran into some strange consolidated loans, which was the brain child of the app i'm making

Comment: All you need is `BalanceAndInterest = new List<BalanceAndInterest>() { // add objects here }`

Comment: Thanks for the help!